# a step function

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be a function defined by

$f: [0,1]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R},\quad t \longmapsto \lfloor tn \rfloor \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$

- Show that $f$ is step function

indeed,

let $\sigma=(x_{k})_{0\leq k \leq n}$ be a regular subdivisions of $[0,1]\ $then for all $\ 0\leq k \leq n-1,$
$$ x_{k}=x_{0}+k.\frac{1-0}{n}=\frac{k}{n}\quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$$
Our goal is to show that f is constant over $(x_{k},x_{k+1})$ that's why i'm trying to calculate 
 $$\forall x^{*}_{k}\in (x_{k},x_{k+1})\quad f(x^{*}_{k})=\lfloor nx^{*}_{k}\rfloor=$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$x_k < x_k^* < x_{k+1}$$ so by definition $$x_0 + \frac{k}{n} < x_k^* < x_0 + \frac{k+1}{n}$$ but $x_0 = 0$ so $$\frac{k}{n} < x_k^* < \frac{k+1}{n}.$$ Multiplying through by $n$ we have $$k < nx_k^* < k+1.$$ Therefore $f(x_k^*) = \lfloor nx_k^*\rfloor = k$.

Comment: Note that $(k < nx_k^* < k+1) \Rightarrow (k \leq nx_k^* < k+1)$.